# Setting bat variables in java AND executing/calling that bat

Tags: java, batch-file

I have 3 Variables in my java class.
I want to set this variables in a bat file and after that execute/call that bat.

before I used this bat for that process

**Config.bat**

```
set PM_Drive = Whatever
set SWG = Whatever
set TOMCAT_HOME = Whatever
call nextbat.bat
```

nextbat.bat needs these variables to work.

How can I do this in java so I don't need **config.bat** anymore?

I tried playing around with ProcessBuilder and  Runtime but I cant figure it out. Maybe someone can help me.

This is my progress so far which obviously does not work.

```
    public void connectTOMCAT(String SWG, String PM_DRIVE, String TOMCAT_HOME) {
    String[] cmdline = {"cmd", "/c", "start cmd.exe", "set SWG", "set PM_DRIVE", "set TOMCAT_HOME" };
    try {;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the spaces from the `SET` command.  The syntax for the set command does not use spaces on either side of the equals symbol.

Comment: TO SET ENV VAR(S) FOR CHILD PROCESS READ INSTRUCTIONS AT [`ProcessBuilder.environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in batch script but I imagine your BAT file contains a call to the JVM like this

```
java -jar my_jar.jar
```

so you could pass your variables as arguments like this

```
java -jar my_jar.jar my_first_arg my_second_arg
```

and retrieve them in your Main method inside your java program.

And if you want to pass these variables as arguments of your bat call, I guess you could do something lihe this :

```
java -jar my_jar.jar %1 %2
```